# PHP Form Not Sending Data To Database

Tags: php, mysql, backend, web-development-server

Could someone please help me and tell me why my php form isn't sending the data to the database.

The types are `emp_no(int11)`, `birth_date(date)`, `first_name(varchar14)`, `last_name(varchar16)`, `gender(enum('M','F')`, `hire_date(date)`

```
 // Checks to see if the save button was pressed and if so, then it should run the 
 query that inserts the data into the data fields specified.
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'employees' ('emp_no', 'birth_date', 'first_name', 
    'last_name', 'gender', 'hire_date')
    VALUES ('".$_POST['emp_no']."', '".$_POST['birth_date']."', 
    '".$_POST['first_name']."', '".$_POST['last_name']."',
    '".$_POST['gender']."', '".$_POST['hire_date']."')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    }
```

code here:
https://codepen.io/blackemr/pen/mjMgPQ

Comment: use print_r($_POST) and send us the results

Comment: You shouldn't wrap column/table names with `'`, instead use the backtick.. `\``

Comment: Code is vuln to sql injection. Protect yourself and your users by switching to [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: @Tom Array ( [emp_no] => 29302 [birth_date] => 2018-05-26 [first_name] => Matthew [last_name] => Blackert [gender] => M [hire_date] => 2018-06-26 [save] => Enter Employee Information )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql) Also a must read or possible duplication could be [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, that didn't work so it's not that.

Comment: remove the single quotes around the column names

Comment: "No, that didn't work so it's not that. " trust me it is.

Comment: .. and around table name

Comment: @Tom it's still not sending the data to the database. $sql = "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date)
        VALUES ('".$_POST['emp_no']."', '".$_POST['birth_date']."', '".$_POST['first_name']."', '".$_POST['last_name']."',
        '".$_POST['gender']."', '".$_POST['hire_date']."')";

Comment: change to $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or trigger_error($conn->error."[ $sql]");

Comment: it should be `mysqli_error()` .. Dont mix MySQLI OOP with procedural call's it's sloppy.  @Tom

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland .. updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date) VALUES ...
```

You can also return the error using:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn));
```